# Is there a way to assign a value to a thing based on where it appears in a list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, if-statement

I have six letters `[a,b,c,d,e,f]` and two users `[bob,bender]`.  They both have a different arrangement of the letters that represents them, think personality score-ish.  Bob is `[e,f,c,b,a,d]` and Bender is `[b,a,d,f,e,c]`.

I also have a chart to put these on.  Each letter, in order, has it's own bar on the chart and the ticks go up to 6.

Depending on where in the list the letter appears it has a number value assigned.  The first letter gets a value of 6, the second a value of 5, and so on.

The final array needs to be in abc order, but with the correct value for each letter.  Example: Bob would end up with `[2,3,4,1,6,5]`.

How would you do this?

The only way I can figure is a ton of if statements and I'm trying to see if there's a better way.

I'm still new to Javascript.

Comment: I´d use an array of objects with both letter and number values so you keep the originial numbers and still be able to sort it or generate the flat number array of it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `Array.map()` and `Array.indexOf()`.

```js
const bob = ['e','f','c','b','a','d'];
const bender = ['b','a','d','f','e','c']
const letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
const bobFinal = letters.map(e => 
  6 - bob.indexOf(e)
);
const benderFinal = letters.map(e =>
  6 - bender.indexOf(e)
);
console.log(bobFinal);
console.log(benderFinal);
```

Here is a function that can be used:

```
const final = arr =>
  letters.map(e =>
    6 - arr.indexOf(e)
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to map the letters and use their index in bobs sequence to extract the score.

```js
const letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
const scores = [6,5,4,3,2,1];

const bob = ['e','f','c','b','a','d'];

const bobScore = letters.map(letter=>scores[bob.indexOf(letter)])

console.log(bobScore);
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach takes the indices from the given array `bob`, sort it with the values ascending and maps the delta of length and actual value.

This solution respects more than one same value.

```js
const
    bob =  ['e', 'f', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'd'],
    result = [...bob.keys()]
        .sort((a, b) => bob[a].localeCompare(bob[b]))
        .map((i, _, { length }) => length - i);

console.log(result); // [2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 5]
```